# Do the exact contrary of append in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a 3D interface with Babylonjs, so I **need** a canvas. Around that canvas I want to implement html elements (with Holy grail layout :  nav to the left, main which is canvas at the middle and aside to the right) according to 2 modes : visualisation and edition.

I have a script to handle the canvas and play with babylonjs functions, and another one to manage the construction of the html according to the chosen mode.

As you can see in my code, I assign my html code to a variable, and append that variable to my holygrail main. However, I don't want my canvas to be recreated each time I change mode, so I implemented it directly in the HTML, it's constant.

My problem is : I want to append elements to my div #insertHere, but also to remove all the elements (excepted my canvas which has to remain) of this #insert div before appending new ones (else I would have several navs and asides).

Can anyone help me ?
Thank for your time !

Here's my construction script :

```
var content = "";
var construct = true;
var visualize = false;

function Create(){
      content = "";

      if(construct == true && visualize == false){
        content += "<div id='1'> <p> hello</p></div><div><p>Insert a lot of html here</p></div>";
        $("insertHere").append(content);
      }
      if(construct == false && visualize == true){
        content += "<div id='not1'><p> Definitely not the same content as the construct one</p></div>";
        $("insertHere").append(content);
      }
}

$(window).ready(function(){
  Create();
  $("#switchmode").click(function(){
    construct = !construct;
    visualize = !visualize;
  // INSERT THE SOLUTION TO CLEAR THE HTML HERE
    CreationPage();
  });
});
```

And here's my HTML (both are short representation of what I really have) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
</head>   
<body id="body" class="HolyGrail">
    <header>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href=".\bootstrap\css\bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="justcontext.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script style="text/javascript" src="scripts/construction.js" defer></script>
      </header>

    <div id='menuonglets' class='btn-group' role='group' aria-label='Basic example'>
      <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary' id='switchmode'>Mode Visu/ Mode Constru</button>
    </div>

    <div class='HolyGrail-body' id='insertHere'>
      <main class='HolyGrail-content'>
          <canvas id='renderCanvas'></canvas>
      </main>
      <!-- Things are inserted here -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery's [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function to remove all elements but the canvas.

Here's a working example:

```js
$("#btn_clear").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $("#insertHere").children().filter(":not(.HolyGrail-content)").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='HolyGrail-body' id='insertHere'>
   <main class='HolyGrail-content' style="background: orange;">
       <canvas id='renderCanvas'></canvas>
   </main>
   
   <p>I'm a paragraph</p>

   <ul>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>bar</li>
   </ul>
</div>

<a href="#" id="btn_clear">Remove all elements but the canvas</a>
```

So:

```
$(window).ready(function(){
  Create();

  $("#switchmode").click(function(){
    construct = !construct;
    visualize = !visualize;

    // Remove all elements, except for the canvas and its container.
    $("#insertHere").children().filter(":not(.HolyGrail-content)").remove();

    CreationPage();
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked also on my code !  I had tried a lot of functions like remove, nextAll, not, etc.. but your filter is what I needed !